# update and insert triggers in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I want to have riggers that set the `last_modified` column automatically each time a row in updated or inserted.
Lets say I have an ID that is unique to each row.

This is my query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_NAME

BEGIN

update TABLE_NAME set last_modified =strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%s','now', 'localtime') where id = old.id;

END;
```

After creating this trigger, when I try to insert I get the error:

```
no such column: old.id
```

I can understand why I get this error, but how can I create a proper trigger?

Comment: `%s` [does not appear to be correct](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html); you probably want `%H:%M:%f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting, there is no old row.

To get the ID of the new row, use `NEW.id`.